# cannot verify JWT- ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, jwt

I am having some issues with verifying the jwt token. The server crashes over and over again if I keep the verify portion. If i comment out the verify portion, then the server runs perfectly.

```
function verifyJWT(req,res,next){
      if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'unauthorized'})
      }
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
//verify portion
      jwt.verify(token , process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,(err,decoded)=>{
        if(err){
          return res.status(403).send({message: 'Forbidden access'})
        }
        console.log('decoded',decoded)
      })
      console.log(token,process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,'inside verifyJWT!',req.headers.authorization)
      
      next()
}
```

Error:
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\3 II\Journey_to_goal\Ms_11_backend\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\3 II\Journey_to_goal\Ms_11_backend\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (D:\3 II\Journey_to_goal\Ms_11_backend\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\3 II\Journey_to_goal\Ms_11_backend\genius-car-service-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at D:\3 II\Journey_to_goal\Ms_11_backend\genius-car-service-server\index.js:86:11
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: is this `index.js:86:11` before or after `console.log('decoded',decoded)`. This means you are modifying the response headers after calling `res.send()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you already sent response in the try block, and you call next outside the try block and after it. Put next() inside try block but after:

> ```
>     if(err){
>       return res.status(403).send({message: 'Forbidden access'})
>     }
> ```

I ran into the same problem and found the cause

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot for the response bro.. though I've fixed that somehow but I dint login for quite a long time.